# Неконсистентное отображение времени

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При рефреше страницы, все времена отображаются как "действие Н **минут** назад":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через минуту происходит обновление времён, и они все внезапно "действие Н **мин.** назад":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Проблема, судя по всему в том, что при первичной загрузке страницы (или после обновления по <kbd>F5</kbd>) время в минутах берётся из строки: [`$minutes$ mins ago`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261801?key=e516521bde7576595707eacc4c9a7e5d), для которой существуют множественные формы (т.е. можно различать 1, 2, 5) и правильные переводы без сокращения слова "минуты".

При автоматическом обновлении по таймеру используются другие строки:

- [`1 min ago / 1 мин. назад`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261977?key=9631187884c39b643d218a0bf46b3126)
- [`$minutes$ mins ago / $minutes$ мин. назад`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261973?key=5bc1cd9d938dd9cc0957e6b7d72ae69a)

где нет возможности различать 2 и 5. Поэтому использована форма с сокращением до "мин.".

Решения тут два:

1. использовать всегда сокращение "мин."
2. убедить разработчиков добавить множественные формы.

Лично я - за второй вариант решения.